# Writing sql code in a php and writing the variable to a file with php

Tags: php, mysql, file, mysqli

I'm trying to write a SQL query into PHP variable and then trying write in a PHP file. When I trigger the code, it gives me "Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in " error.

Here is my variable.

Thanks for your help

```
$txt = " $conn = mysqli_connect('shareddb1c.hosting.stackcp.net','egitimde-adresim-323044d1','','egitimde-adresim-323044d1');

    mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');

    $only_query = 'SELECT * FROM anaokulu_veritabani WHERE anaokulu_id = 63';

    $yayinda_query = mysqli_query($conn, $only_query);

    if($yayinda_array = mysqli_fetch_array($yayinda_query)) {

        if($yayinda_array[online] == 0 ) {

            header('Location:http://www.egitimdeadres.com');

        } 

}";
```

Comment: use `single quote` instead of `double quotes` At the start and end

Comment: No, you are _not_ trying to write a "sql query" into a variable (which would be a standard thing), you are trying to write a full php script into a php variable and execute it (which is often attempted by people new to programming and never makes much sense).

Comment: thanks for help i 'm trying right now

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes istead of double, because PHP will parse your variables under double quotes.
In your example be careful about single quotes inside your string use double quotes or escape them.